# How to use dygraphs and DT in slidify?

Tags: html, widget, slidify

I'm trying to use the packages DT and dygraphs into my slidify presentation in R. However, it seems it's not as straightforward as I thought. Is there any extra command I need to add in order to use the htmlwidgets produced by the datatable() and dygraphs() commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible at the time:

https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues/414